# php $_POST count issue

Tags: php

what would be the best approach to get count of $_POST

i have a form where a user can create a input box, so i don't want to allow empty submission.

i tried `count($_POST)`, it always empty. This in

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
//codes
}
else {
die(count($_POST)); // return as empty
}
```

What would be the best way to get count of $_POST?

Comment: Are you sure that your form has POST method?

Comment: Yes, $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] returns POST

Answer (score 8):

Do note that it's an integer you're passing to `die()` (alias for [`exit()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php))! This has a *special meaning*:

> If `status` [the argument] is an integer, that value
>   will be used as the exit status and
>   **not printed**. Exit statuses should be
>   in the range 0 to 254, the exit status
>   255 is reserved by PHP and shall not
>   be used. The status 0 is used to
>   terminate the program successfully.

<sup>(My emphasis)</sup>

Easy work-around:

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   //codes
} else {
   die('count=' . count($_POST)); // Now a String
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work :) are you sure you are requesting using POST, you can check $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].

Another problem could be if you are using a very old version of PHP ? are you using a version lower than PHP 4.1, the superglobal arrays might not exists.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.predefined.php

Comment: i am very sure i'm using POST method and im using php 5.2

Comment: Try replacing the die(count($_POST)) with var_dump($_POST); and let me know the output :)